# Display data in product category view (from already working modification)

Tags: php, opencart2.3

opencart 2.3.0.2, how to display data that this modification is adding but in category view (where the product list, before product price), i understand that need to add code in controller category.php model category.php and category.tpl but adding same code that come for compare or other places not working.

modification full xml code,

```
<modification>

    <id>additional_product</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
    <author>ovife21</author>
    
    <file name="admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl" error="skip">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php echo $text_stock_status; ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $additional_product; ?>"><?php echo $text_additionalproduct; ?></a></li>]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file> 
    
    <file name="admin/controller/common/menu.php" error="skip">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$data['text_product']]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$data['text_additionalproduct'] = $this->language->get('text_additionalproduct');]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$data['product']]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$data['additional_product'] = $this->url->link('localisation/additional_product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file> 
    
    <file name="admin/language/*/common/menu.php" error="skip">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$_['text_product']]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$_['text_additionalproduct']                     = 'Additional Product Fields';]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>     
    <file name="admin/controller/common/column_left.php" error="skip">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA['access', 'localisation/stock_status']]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                        
            if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'localisation/additional_product')) {
                $localisation[] = array(
                    'name'     => 'Additional Product Fields',
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('localisation/additional_product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true),
                    'children' => array()   
                );
            }]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file> 
    <file name="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($data['product_attribute'])) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            
            if (isset($data['product_to_field'])) {
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            foreach ($data['product_to_field'] as $language_id => $product_to_field) {
                foreach ($product_to_field as $additional_product_id => $product_to_field_value) {
                    
                        $dropdown_query = $this->db->query("SELECT dropdown FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "additional_product WHERE language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' and additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "'");
                        
                        $dropdown = $dropdown_query->row['dropdown'];
                        
                                                
                        if (!($dropdown))
                            {                               
                            $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_to_field_value['name']) . "'");
                            }
                            else {
                            $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field SELECT '" . (int)$product_id . "', '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "', language_id, value from " . DB_PREFIX . "additional_product_value WHERE additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "' and additional_product_value_id = '" .  $product_to_field_value['name'] . "'");
                            }
                    
                }
            }
        }
            
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
        
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            
            if (isset($data['product_to_field'])) {
            
            foreach ($data['product_to_field'] as $language_id => $product_to_field) {
                foreach ($product_to_field as $additional_product_id => $product_to_field_value) {
                    
                        $dropdown_query = $this->db->query("SELECT dropdown FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "additional_product WHERE language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' and additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "'");
                        
                        $dropdown = $dropdown_query->row['dropdown'];
                        
                                                
                        if (!($dropdown))
                            {                               
                            $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_to_field_value['name']) . "'");
                            }
                            else {
                            $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field SELECT '" . (int)$product_id . "', '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "', language_id, value from " . DB_PREFIX . "additional_product_value WHERE additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "' and additional_product_value_id = '" .  $product_to_field_value['name'] . "'");
                            }
                    
                }
            }
            
            /*foreach ($data['product_to_field'] as $language_id => $product_to_field) {
                foreach ($product_to_field as $additional_product_id => $product_to_field_value) {
                                
                        $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', additional_product_id = '" . (int)$additional_product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_to_field_value['name']) . "'");
                    
                }
            }*/
        }
            
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
                
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>     
    
    <file name="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->post['shipping'])) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            
            $this->load->model('localisation/additional_product');
            $data['config_language_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
        
            if (isset($this->request->post['additional_product'])) {
                    $additional_products = $this->request->post['additional_product'];
                } else {
                    $additional_products = $this->model_localisation_additional_product->getAdditionalProductes();
                } 
            
            foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) {
                if (!(isset($additional_product['dropdown'])) || !($additional_product['dropdown'])) {
                    $data['additional_products'][] = array(
                        'field' => $additional_product['name'],
                        'id' => $additional_product['additional_product_id'],
                        'dropdown' => 0
                    );
                } else {
                    $data['additional_products'][] = array(
                        'field' => $additional_product['name'],
                        'id' => $additional_product['additional_product_id'],
                        'dropdown' => $additional_product['dropdown'],
                        'values' => $this->model_localisation_additional_product->getAdditionalProductValues($additional_product['additional_product_id'])
                    );
                }
            }
            
            if (isset($this->request->post['product_to_field'])) {
                    $data['product_to_field'] = $this->request->post['product_to_field'];
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                    $data['product_to_field'] = $this->model_localisation_additional_product->getAdditionalProductDescriptionsbyProductId($this->request->get['product_id']);
                } else {
                    $data['product_to_field'] = array();
                }
            
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>     
    
    <file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before" index="1"><![CDATA[<?php echo $entry_location; ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if (isset($additional_products)) {foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) { ?>
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-<?php echo $additional_product['field']; ?>"><?php echo $additional_product['field']; ?></label>
              <?php if (!(isset($additional_product['dropdown'])) || !($additional_product['dropdown'])) { ?>
              <div class="col-sm-10"><?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                  <input type="text" name="product_to_field[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][<?php echo $additional_product['id']; ?>][name]" 
                  value="<?php echo isset($product_to_field[$language['language_id']][$additional_product['id']]) ? $product_to_field[$language['language_id']][$additional_product['id']]['name'] : ''; ?>" />
                  <img src="<?php echo ((VERSION >= '2.3.0.0')? "language/".$language['code']."/".$language['code'].".png" : "view/image/flags/".$language['image']); ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /><br />
                  <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                  <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></span><br />
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
              </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="product_to_field[<?php echo $config_language_id; ?>][<?php echo $additional_product['id']; ?>][name]">
              <option value="-1"></option>
              <?php foreach ($additional_product['values'] as $additional_product_value_id => $value) { ?>          
                                
                <?php if ((!empty($product_to_field) && !empty($value) && (isset($value[$config_language_id])) && (isset($product_to_field[$config_language_id][$additional_product['id']]))) && ($value[$config_language_id]['value'] == $product_to_field[$config_language_id][$additional_product['id']]['name'])) { ?>          
                  <option value="<?php echo $additional_product_value_id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $value[$config_language_id]['value']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $additional_product_value_id; ?>"><?php echo $value[$config_language_id]['value']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>                 
                
              <?php } ?>
              </select>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
            <?php } } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>     
    
    <file name="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field ptf ON (p.product_id = ptf.product_id)]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($word)) . "%']]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($word)) . "%' OR LCASE(ptf.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($word)) . "%']]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%']]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%' OR LCASE(ptf.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%']]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[public function getProductImages($product_id) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            public function getAdditionalProductes($data = array()) {
                
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT additional_product_id, name, display FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "additional_product WHERE language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY sort");
            
                        $additional_product_data = $query->rows;
                        
                        return $additional_product_data;                        
            }
            
            public function getAdditionalProductDescriptionsbyProductId($product_id) {
                $product_to_field = array();
                
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' and language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
                
                foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                    $product_to_field[$result['additional_product_id']] = array('name' => $result['name']);
                }
                return $product_to_field;
            }

            
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>     
    
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[$data['images'] = array();]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            
            $data['additional_products'] = array();
            
            $additional_products = $this->model_catalog_product->getAdditionalProductes();
                        
            foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) {
                
                $data['additional_products'][] = array(
                    'field' => $additional_product['name'],
                    'id' => $additional_product['additional_product_id'],
                    'display' => $additional_product['display']
                );
            }
            
            $data['product_to_field'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getAdditionalProductDescriptionsbyProductId($this->request->get['product_id']);
                                    
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>
    
        
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php echo $text_stock; ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if (isset($additional_products) && !empty($additional_products)) {foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) { ?>
            <?php if (isset($product_to_field[$additional_product['id']]) && ($product_to_field[$additional_product['id']]['name'] <> '') && ($additional_product['display'])) { ?>
              <span><?php echo $additional_product['field']; ?>:</span>
              <?php echo $product_to_field[$additional_product['id']]['name']; ?>
              <br />
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            
            ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/compare.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$data['attribute_groups'] = array();]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $data['additional_products'] = array();
            
            $additional_products = $this->model_catalog_product->getAdditionalProductes();
                        
            foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) {
                
                $data['additional_products'][] = array(
                    'field' => $additional_product['name'],
                    'id' => $additional_product['additional_product_id'],
                    'display' => $additional_product['display']
                );
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>    
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[$attribute_data = array();]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $product_to_field = array();
            $product_to_field = $this->model_catalog_product->getAdditionalProductDescriptionsbyProductId($product_id);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA['attribute'    => $attribute_data,]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA['attribute'    => $attribute_data, 'product_to_field'    => $product_to_field, ]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/compare.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[<td><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></td>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if (isset($additional_products)) { foreach ($additional_products as $additional_product) { ?>
            
                <td><?php echo $additional_product['field']; ?></td>
              <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <td><?php if (isset($products[$product['product_id']]['product_to_field'][$additional_product['id']]['name'])) {echo $products[$product['product_id']]['product_to_field'][$additional_product['id']]['name'];} ?></td>
               <?php } ?>
             </tr>
            <tr>        
            
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>    
                
    </file>

</modification>
```

adding code part for compare view to catalog view